# the development server returned response error code: 500 origin module path does'n exist

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njrPS.png)
bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `native-base` from `F:\source\React Native\appname\src\components\LoginForm.js`: Module `native-base` does not exist in the Haste module map

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the package native-base from package.json but you are using it in LoginForm.js

1. Follow the steps described here :https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html to integrate native-base with your project.
2. Terminate the packager instance.
3. run react-native run-ios or react-native run-android

NOTE : also please remove the spacing you have in your project folder path :
it should be F:\source\React-Native\appname\src\components\LoginForm.js